# How to store dynamic sized entity in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

So i am making a relational schema for health insurance plans but i do not know how to store them in MySql. My problem is a health plans have drug coverages represented by Tiers. A certain drug falls under a tier and then the tier has pricing information. The problem is different plans have different amount of tiers

Example

Tier 1 : 25$ copay; Tier 2 : 50 $ copay after deductible. 
Tier 1 : 25$ copay; Tier 2 : 50 $ copay after deductible; Tier 3 : 25% coinsurance.

How can i store a plan in MySql that will make sense? I can not make each row a unique plan since i do not know how many tiers will be present. Should i make another table that stores this information and links back to a plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description , my understanding is that a plan has many tiers and a tier could belong to many plans. So, if you create a many to many relationship between `Plan` <-> `Tier`, won't it serve your purpose?

In the logical data model, this will decompose into an association table (or gerund entity).
 See example here: [Many-to-many relationship](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

In this case, you can create a `Plan_Tiers` table, which can hold the `planId` and `tierId`. You can have the required attributes like `co-pay`, `copay after deductible`, etc in the entity `Tier`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment turns out this is exactly what i ended up doing. Wasnt exactly sure if i could break a plan down like that but when i did it made sense obviously.